# why doesn't this work to screen for Boolean inputs?

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I routinely sanitize the inputs to a function using this sort of technique:

```
funcI[x_Integer] := Print[x];
```

But it doesn't work with Booleans.

```
func[x_Boolean] := Print[x];

func[4] (* doesn't execute, as expected *)

func[True] (* doesn't execute, but it should, right? *)
```

As a workaround, I can use `func2[x_ /; BooleanQ[x]] := Print[x];`, but why doesn't the simpler formulation work?

```
func2[True] (* works just fine *)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x_Integer` is a pattern which catches an `x` so long as the `Head` of `x` is identical to `Integer`. Booleans have no such head:

```
{Head[True], Head[False]}
```

> {Symbol, Symbol}

Thus, `x_Boolean` will not match `True` or `False`, since `Symbol` is not identically equal to `Boolean`.

You may instead use `x_?BooleanQ`, which is a pattern which catches an `x` so long as `BooleanQ[x]` is identically `True`.

Answer (score 6):

`BooleanQ[]` is new in version 10, so eyorble's approach is what I'll recommend for current code. (A hint that your initial approach would not have worked is that neither `Head[True]` nor `Head[False]` return `Boolean`, which is the pattern you were trying to match in your original definition.) In the old days, this is what I'd do (and using a different example):

```
func[x : True | False] := Boole[x]

func /@ {True, False, π, xxx}
   {1, 0, func[π], func[xxx]}
```